# javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000131. Cascaded validation in hierarchical objects

Tags: java, spring, mockito, hibernate-validator, javax.validation

I have the next hierarchy:

```
public class A extends B {
   @Valid 
   public A(String languageCode, C token) {
      super(languageCode, token);
   }  
}
```

The B class has a property call language code that should be validated with @NotEmpty only if a service has the @Validated({RequiringLanguageCode.class})

```
 public class B extends D {

    private String languageCode;

    @Valid
    public B(String languageCode, C token) {
        super(token);
        this.languageCode = languageCode;
    }

    @NotEmpty(groups = {RequiringLanguageCode.class})
    public String getLanguageCode() {
        return languageCode;
    }
}
```

Now, D is the base class that has a C property that should be validated as NotNull and also the values that are inside the C class.

```
public class D {

    private C token;

    @Valid
    public D(C token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    @NotNull
    public C getToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

C class contains two String that are validated as @NotEmpty:

```
public class C {

    private String value1;

    private String value2;

    public C(String value1,
            String value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    @NotEmpty
    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    @NotEmpty
    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
}
```

**When trying to test this using mockito the values of C class aren't validated if the token values (value1 and value2) are empty.**

**Can somebody help me?**
**Does somebody have any idea about what is happening?**

The test are as followed:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ATest {

    @Autowired
    private AAssembler aAssembler;

    @Mock
    A request;

    @Mock
    C token;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(token.getValue1()).thenReturn("");
        when(token.getValue2()).thenReturn("key");
        when(request.getToken()).thenReturn(token);
        assertThatIllegalArgumentException()
           .isThrownBy(() -> aAssembler.build(request));
    }
}
```

The AAssembler is annotated as @Validated({RequiringLanguageCode.class})

The reason why I launch an IllegalArgumentException instead of ConstraintViolationException is something out of scope of this problem. I catch the constraint violation an throw the IllegalArgumentException instead.

The Assembler build method has also a constraint annotated as :

```
public Response build(@Valid @NotNull A request) {
....
}
```

I would be very thankful if somebody can help me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem `javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000131: A method return value must not be marked for cascaded validation more than once in a class hierarchy, but the following two methods are marked as such:` while testing REST services annotated with `javax.validation.valid`.

Based on this AutoValue [issue](https://github.com/google/auto/issues/682) I thought maybe the same happens here, too. Mockito [copies](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#withoutAnnotations--) by default all annotations. So I was able to resolve this problem by preventing this.

```
A stub = Mockito.mock(A.class, withSettings().withoutAnnotations());
```

The disadvantage compared to the AutoValue solution no annotation will be copied. So if you need them you're stuck.

Regards Christian

Comment: Thanks it helps! https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7033#issuecomment-748047164